# function is not able to properly write output data file - Python

Tags: python, flush

Scenario:

I have two files, *file1 size = 19.7MB* and *file2 size = 446KB*. I am running the following code to process the data from both files and get an output data file. But after a certain output file size (332KB) the program stops writing data to the output file. I tried using `flush()` function but again the output file contains the exact same size as output file without using `flush()` function (and took exact same time to write these data in both conditions (file created and last modifed)) while loop is still running.

Please someone suggest the potential reason(s)? Should I use `sleep()` function to wake up the program after a certain time? Thanks

```
with open("file2",'rU') as gg:
    for g in gg:
        g = g.rstrip().split('\t')
        with open(file1) as cc:
            c = c.rstrip().split('\t')
                if int(c[0]) == int(g[0]) and int(c[1]) >= int(g[2]) and int(g[3]) >= int(c[1]):
                    with open('output.txt', 'a') as ii:
                        ii.write(c[1]+'\t'+'\t'.join(g)+'\n')
                        ii.flush()
```

Comment: Are you still accessing to the `if` condition?

Comment: And I think your code in line `c = c.rstrip().split('\t')` should actually be `c = cc.rstrip().split('\t')`

Comment: Since you're conditionally writing to your output file, it seems possible that the condition is only so (few?) times satisfied that the total output is, in fact, 332KB.

Answer (score 0):

You are creating too many connections to the same file and there is an operating system limit on this type of operations.

try unnesting your script as much as possible

```
    new_list = []
    with open("file2",'rU') as gg:
        for g in gg:
            g = g.rstrip().split('\t')
            with open(file1) as cc:
                c = cc.rstrip().split('\t')
                if int(c[0]) == int(g[0]) and int(c[1]) >= int(g[2]) and int(g[3]) >= int(c[1]):
                    new_list.append(c[1]+'\t'+'\t'.join(g)+'\n')

    with open('output.txt', 'a') as ii:
        for e in new_list:
                    ii.write(e)
```

Comment: While the overall advice is sound, it doesn't look like there are too many connections (at once). Just a lot of open-close actions for the same files.